# cannot find context with specified id undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to create an app that does a google image search of a random word and selects/clicks the first result image.

I am successful until the code is attempting to select the result image and it throws the following error in my terminal:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection 
 id: 1): Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Cannot find 
 context with specified id undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
const pup = require('puppeteer');
const random = require('random-words');
const url = 'http://images.google.com';

(async() => {
  const browser = await pup.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url);
  const searchBar = await page.$('#lst-ib');
  await searchBar.click();
  await page.keyboard.type(`${random()}`);
  const submit = await page.$('#mKlEF');
  await submit.click();
  await page.keyboard.type(random());
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  const pic = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelectorAll('img');
  });

  pic.click();
})();
```

Comment: See [When would an error "Cannot find context with specified id undefined" happen? #1325](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1325).

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelectorAll('img')` is not serialisable, so it returns undefined (see this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2420) as reference)

Please use something like: (depends on which element you want to click)

```
await page.$$eval('img', elements => elements[0].click());
```

Comment: i tried the code you supplied and the original error is resolved. however, this is what happens: chrome navigates to google images, a random word is entered into the search bar and the results page is displayed but then it seems as though the browser refreshes but goes to google.com, not images.google.com. and sometimes instead of 'refreshing' it throws a different error: 'cannot read property 'click' of undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long dead thread but if anyone runs into this issue and the above answer does not apply to you, try adding a simple `await page.waitForTimeout(2000)`. My test was completing but I was getting this error when attempting to `await browser.close();` Adding the wait after searching for my final selector seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: `page.waitForTimeout` isn't a good way to wait for something to happen. It just adds a race condition, introducing false positives and slowing tests/scrapes down for no reason. It technically _works_ in many cases, but it's basically a last resort, opting out of the event-driven architecture Puppeteer recommends.